# Change search() locations without unloading packages

Tags: r

I am using code which depends on two packages that conflict. I would like to give one priority for only a short period of time and my plan is to just move it up to the front of search(). However, I can't just unload and reload. I tried that and it causes other problems, and running `library` on an already loaded package does not work.

Here is an example (the real use case involves non-CRAN packages):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)

> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:MASS"      "package:ggplot2"  
 [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
 [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

How can I now move package:ggplot2 ahead of package:MASS without detaching/unloading ggplot2?

EDIT

Inside the function I need to call, say `function1`, there is an expression that makes further calls. I cannot edit those calls to append `::`.

e.g.

```
unchangeable <- function1("abc") ~ function2("def")
```

Suppose `mainFun` is the one I want to call. I can do

```
mainFun(unchangeable)
```

but I cannot specify

```
mainFun::unchangeable
```

It is indeed possible to edit `unchangeable` by manipulating formula objects. But that is not ideal and I need a more general solution for an object of other types.

EDIT2:

Here is an example, which shows a similar problem.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gam)

y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)

thisformula <- y ~ s(x)

gamgam <- gam(thisformula)
# s <- mgcv::s
mgcvgam <- mgcv::gam(thisformula)
```

This gives me the error

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Uncommenting the line `s <- mgcv::s` solves the problem in this case. But in my more general case it doesn't, and in any case it seems like a hack. How can I have all functions that are called within `mgcv::gam` first be looked up in `mgcv`?

Comment: Then why not `mainFun(mainFun::unchangeable)` ?  I think you need to post the actual code and masked functions to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Carl. Unfortunately I cannot widdle it down to a minimal example and the code contains code from a professor who does not feel comfortable having his code online (despite my attempts). I'm still interested in the general question also of whether one can change the search order.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the function in the specific package using `::`. For example `ggplot2::labs` will always refer to that function under `ggplot2` even if it is masked by some later package being loaded

Comment: thanks for the response. I should have been more clear. Inside the function I need to call is an expression that makes further calls. I cannot edit those calls to append `::`. I will edit.

Comment: That's odd: why can't you edit a function?  If all else fails, copy the function source and modify a local version.

Comment: Can you redefine that function so that it is now in the global environment? That is, after loading a package that has `labs` after `ggplot2`, you could redefine the function to point to the `ggplot2` version: `labs <- ggplot2::labs`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft because the functions come with the package. See the example.

Comment: @ilir that works in this case but not in the more general case I'm working with and can't seem to minimize it to a mwe. I would prefer to avoid redefining.